# Preventing the first line on list elements becoming orphan

Tags: lists, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I have a document with a long list of items in enumerate and itemize environments, some of these start with a single line followed of a long (or sort) paragraph:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item short sentence no more than a line.
% I definitely don't want the page break here
very long paragraph, with lots of text but which 
I wouldn't mind to break between pages.
% I wouldn't mind a break here
\item another item with a some what long sentence
% but it shouldn't break here
Another long paragraph which I wouldn't mind to break.
\end{itemize}
```

I want to prevent the first line from being separated from the rest of the text, but in a way that doesn't prevent page breaks on the longer paragraphs, like minipage or samepage. There seems to be a comment describing a piece of code from [`ltlists.dtx`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltlists.dtx) that seems to be meant to prevent the case I'm seeing:

> This code is intended to **prevent a page break after the first line of an item** that comes immediately after a section title. It may be sensible to always forbid a page break after one line of an item? As with all such settings of `\clubpenalty` it is local so will have no effect if the item starts in a group.

But only applies if it's after a title, which is not this specific case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: There aren't any paragraphs in what you've shown. But a paragraph break is a better page break than in the middle of a paragraph, typographically. I suspect that you should not be using an `itemize` environment here and that you really want something else.

Comment: @Andrew the problem is representable by what I've shown. There isn't anything "fancy" about it.

Comment: @cfr it's a list of elements with a short introductory line, and then paragraphs. I don't know how how else to represent them other than using enumerate/itemize.

Comment: As far as I can see your code does not compile, it doesn't contain paragraphs and it doesn't produce any widows. So, sorry, but I don't think it's a MWE :) The point of providing a MWE is that it gives people have something to work from or, if you like, some code to fix. To ask people to construct an example that exhibits your problem *and* then solve it is a little OTT. A MWE also clarifies exactly what your problem is and so avoids people wasting their time solving a different problem.

Comment: @Andrew because producing a real widow implies that I have to paste lots irrelevant text, which wouldn't help to ilustrate the problem. Second, it [has paragraphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37962/33619) by common definition, that you don't want to see them is another issue. Third MWE isn't necessary to solve the question *"How to prevent page breaks that create widows in the list environments?"*, which has been sufficiently explained in both title and body of the question, and hasn't been a problem for [other questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142/33619) that merely ask how-to.

Comment: Your code contains no paragraphs. It is not a question of seeing them. The definition of `itemize` is class and package dependent. It is necessary to have some widows in order to recreate the issue. Hence, an MWE including widows is required. In any case, an MWE must compile by definition. An MNWE is suitable if asking for help with an error.

Comment: There are many poor questions on this site. This question and the one you linked are both among them. Votes are frequently inversely proportional to quality. In general, there is no relation between quality and vote counts or quality and popularity. Recent political events surely proved that, if nothing else.

Comment: Anyway, one way to prevent widows is to use \needspace from the needspace package.

Comment: @cfr then why in "List, and related environments" which describes "The generic commands for creating an indented environment – enumerate, itemize, quote" contains commands like: \listparindent which is "extra indentation at **beginning of every paragraph of a list** except the one started by the \item command"? Stop fussing over it. Latex says they are paragraphs, and it uses the `\par` command to create paragraphs. So my usage of "paragraphs" is by "source code" correct.

Comment: @JohnKormylo do that applies for an entire environment or I have to apply it everywhere I don't want a new page?

Comment: We pointed out that there are no paragraphs in your example code. If there were paragraphs, they would indeed be paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute [`\needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) at the start of every `\item`. This will decide whether a page break should be made or not, depending on the amount of space left on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,needspace,etoolbox,geometry}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand{\item}{%
    \par\needspace{\dimexpr\itemsep+2\baselineskip}%
    \olditem}%
}

\geometry{textheight=40\baselineskip}%
%\geometry{textheight=39\baselineskip}% This will make entire second \item go to next page.

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{itemize}
  \item
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ac 
  mauris fringilla, interdum quam et, tincidunt orci. Duis dictum auctor 
  ante, a ultrices diam pulvinar molestie. Nam massa tellus, tristique et 
  laoreet ut, ultrices vitae tellus.
  Proin feugiat ipsum tortor, non aliquam nisl gravida et. Sed imperdiet 
  arcu aliquam, dictum diam nec, pharetra tortor. Integer id eleifend dolor, 
  vel rhoncus nisi. Nam aliquam leo nisi, quis tincidunt ex sollicitudin nec. 
  Duis vitae ultrices nibh.

  \item
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ac 
  mauris fringilla, interdum quam et, tincidunt orci. Duis dictum auctor 
  ante, a ultrices diam pulvinar molestie. Nam massa tellus, tristique et 
  laoreet ut, ultrices vitae tellus.
  Proin feugiat ipsum tortor, non aliquam nisl gravida et. Sed imperdiet 
  arcu aliquam, dictum diam nec, pharetra tortor. Integer id eleifend dolor, 
  vel rhoncus nisi. Nam aliquam leo nisi, quis tincidunt ex sollicitudin nec. 
  Duis vitae ultrices nibh.

\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) taps into the `itemize` environment, updating `\item` to check for `\itemsep+2\baselineskip` remaining on the page. You may have to play around with these values to get something to work in your specific case.

Comment: I've set `textheight` at 45 which seems to be the best not creating widows or orphans later.